# Rows with multiple corresponding values in the same table

Tags: sql, db2

Suppose I have a table

```
Name          Wear
Martin        Hat
Martin        ?
Martin        Shirt
Alfred        Tee
Alfred        Jeans
```

And I only want names of people whose Wear value is fully given, that is without a NULL (?) value in there.

I thought about using a group by ... having Wear <> NULL but this isn't sufficient, as there can be more than one Wear value.

In this case, I would like to only return 'Alfred'.

Comment: Hint: `count(*)` counts all rows, `count(Wear)` counts non-null values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like

```
HAVING SUM(Wear IS NULL) = 0
```

or

```
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(Wear)
```

Comment: For some reason, the first option throws an -199 error on DB2. The second one works wonder however!

Answer (score 2):

Use correlated subquery

```
select distinct name from tablename a where not exists 
    (select 1 from tablename b where a.name=b.name and wear is null)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `not exists` :

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1 from table t1 where t1.name = t.name and t1.wear is null);
```

If you want name only then you can do aggregation :

```
select name
from table t
group by name
having sum (wear is null ) = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
select name
from mytable m
where not exists (
   select 1 
   from mytable i 
   where i.name = m.name 
   and i.wear is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume your table name is 'users', then use below sub query

```
SELECT * FROM `users` where Wear IS NOT NULL AND Name NOT IN (SELECT Name from `users` where Wear IS NULL)
```